# Animate parent div and move children

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate, carousel

I have a click event bound this this function:

```
animateItem: function (container, distance, speed) {
    var double = "-" + distance;
    var currentMargin = parseInt($(container).css("margin-left"));

    if (double >= currentMargin) {               
        $(".carousel-item").first().hide(speed, function () {
            $(this).appendTo(container).show();
        });
    } else {
        $(container).animate({ "margin-left": "-=" + distance + "px" }, speed);
    }
}
```

and this works perfectly. It stops animating the container and instead moves the first element to the end of the container which mimics the animation.

Now I want to create a continuous loop, I have tried with this :

```
$(self.settings.itemContainerClass).animate({ "margin-left": "-=" + width * 50 + "px" }, {
    duration: 500 * 50,
    step: function (now, fx) {
        if (width >= now) {
            $(self.settings.itemClass).first().appendTo(self.settings.itemContainerClass);
        }
    }
});
```

but this just doesnt work.
Can anyone give me some insight into what I can try?

Cheers,
/r3plica

Comment: What's the `-=` you're prepending to your styles?

Comment: sorry, that is the width of the items contained within the container

Comment: Have a live example we could look at? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: http://r3plica.co.uk is where my code is sat atm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was animating the children, but found that on a continuous loop it jerked. After attempting to use margins, I re-visited the jquery site and the definition for **animate** I realised that the default effect for animate is "swing", which is what was causing my jerking.
So, I amended my code to this:

```
animateItem: function (self, speed) {
    var $item = $(self.settings.itemClass).first();
    var width = $item.outerWidth(true);
    var left = parseInt($item.css("left"));

    if (left < 0) {
        self.moveItem(self, speed, 1);
    } else {
        $item.animate({ "left": "-" + width + "px" }, {
            duration: speed,
            easing: "linear",
            step: function (now, fx) {
                $(self.settings.itemClass + ":gt(0)").css("left", now);
            }
        });
    }
},
moveItem: function (self, speed, count) {
    if (count > 0) {
        var $item = $(self.settings.itemClass).first();
        $item.hide(speed, "linear", function () {
            $(this).appendTo(self.settings.itemContainerClass).show(speed, "linear");
            self.moveItem(self, speed, count - 1); // Repeat
        });
    }
},
```

This just animates a single object, to get the idea of what an object can look like, here is some html :)

```
<div id="carousel" class="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-container">
        <div class="carousel-item yellow">
            <div class="carousel-photo">
                <img src="http://www.csupomona.edu/~ieee/profile/2012/uman.png" />
            </div>
            <p>Hicks, Bill</p>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item green">
            <div class="carousel-photo">
                <img src="http://www.csupomona.edu/~ieee/profile/2012/uman.png" />
            </div>
            <p>Jeremy, Ron</p>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item blue">
            <div class="carousel-photo">
                <img src="http://www.csupomona.edu/~ieee/profile/2012/uman.png" />
            </div>
            <p>Little, John</p>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item violet">
            <div class="carousel-photo">
                <img src="http://www.csupomona.edu/~ieee/profile/2012/uman.png" />
            </div>
            <p>Smith, Will</p>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item purple">
            <div class="carousel-photo">
                <img src="http://www.csupomona.edu/~ieee/profile/2012/uman.png" />
            </div>
            <p>Shakespear, William</p>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item pink">
            <div class="carousel-photo">
                <img src="http://www.csupomona.edu/~ieee/profile/2012/uman.png" />
            </div>
            <p>Jameson, Jenny</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

To animate constantly, I created this function:

```
animateWheel: function (self, speed, count) {
    var $item = $(self.settings.itemClass).first();
    var width = $item.outerWidth(true);

    $item.animate({ "left": "-" + width + "px" }, {
        duration: speed,
        easing: "linear",
        step: function (now, fx) {
            $(self.settings.itemClass + ":gt(0)").css("left", now);
        },
        complete: function () {
            self.moveItem(self, speed, count);
        }
    });
},
```

And my options look like this:

```
defaults = {
    itemsPerPage: 4.5,
    itemContainerClass: '.carousel-container',
    itemClass: '.carousel-item',
    startButton: '#start',
    carouselPage: '#carouselPage',
    contentElement: '.ui-content'
};
```

Hopefully that will give someone else having the same issue some idea of what to do :) My next stage is to try and slow down the animation (for the continuous loop) before it stops